# bootstrap dropdown mobile view issue stretch the navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i am using and created a bootstrap navabar and in that dropdown in desktop view it work perfectly fine but in mobile view it stretch the navbar like this i want to avoid because it look ugly
here is the screenshot what I am talking about:

[image]

here is my code

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #025;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="{% url 'accounts:home' %}" style="font-size: 25px; font-weight:600;">
      <img src="{% static 'image/logo/logo.png' %}" class="d-inline-block align-text-center logo-img" style="margin-left: 150px; height: 40px;"> BuyBuy
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-nav dekstop_search">
      <form class="form-inline" action="{% url 'products:search' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search" name="search" required>
        <button class="btn sea btn-outline-primary" type="submit" value="Search"><i class="fas fa-search text-white"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Links -->
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <!-- Right -->
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white text-center"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
          <span class="badge" style="background-color: white; color:#025; padding:3px;">{{wish|length}}</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white text-center"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
            <span class="badge" style="background-color: white; color:#025; padding:3px;">{{wish|length}}</a>
      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{% url 'orders:cart' %}"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            <span class="badge" style="background-color: white; color:#025; padding:3px;">{{request.session.cart.keys|length}}</span></a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <img class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="height:50px; border-radius: 50%; margin-right:150px;" src="{{ user.profile.profile_pic.url }}">
        <div class="dropdown-menu drop" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <li class="item text-center" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Hi <strong style="color: #B9C04C; cursor:default;"> {{ user.username }}  </strong></li>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="{% url 'accounts:profile'  request.user.username %}">My Account</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="{% url 'orders:myorders' %}">My Order</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#">My Address</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#">My Cart</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Log Out</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#">Settings</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#">Help</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{% url 'orders:cart' %}"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            <span class="badge" style="background-color: white; color:#025; padding:3px;">{{request.session.cart.keys|length}}</span></a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary text-white">Log In</button></a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</nav>
```

i didn't tried anything becuase i don't know what to do any suggestion will be helpfull i want it to be like that in mobile view too:

[image]

current error[image]

css

```
.drop{
  position: absolute !important;
  left: auto !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example so we can help you.

Comment: @Lalalena i didn't i am mainly in backend i am not very good in frontend this why i am looking for answer I did not understand how to solve it that i why i asked here

Comment: Add second class to the `<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-your-class" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">` (to prevent bootstrap class overriding) and set style `position: absolute;` to it. Like  `.navbar .navbar-nav .dropdown-your-class { position: absolute; }` or `.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu.dropdown-your-class { position: absolute; }`

Comment: @Marii i does solve the problem but it expand the width  i added the screenshot

Comment: @Marii Add in the last of the question

Comment: Try to change left or right position of dropdown menu , wrap it with media query (to not break desktops). Like right: 0; left: auto . Parent must have position: relative.

Comment: now it comes in center

Comment: @Marii updated the screenshot

Comment: Does .dropdown has position: relative?

Comment: yes .dropdown has position: relative